# Functions and objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Write a function 'transformFirstAndLast' that takes in an array, and returns an object with:

1. The first element of the array as the object's key, and
2. The last element of the array as that key's value.

Example input:

['Queen', 'Elizabeth', 'Of Hearts', 'Beyonce'],

The function's return value (output):

```
{
  Queen: 'Beyonce'
}
```

Note that the input array may have a varying number of elements. Your code should flexibly accommodate that.

E.g. it should handle input like:

```
['Kevin', 'Bacon', 'Love', 'Hart', 'Costner', 'Spacey']
```

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
function transformFirstAndLast(array) {
  var arrayList = ['Queen', 'Elizabeth', 'Of Hearts', 'Beyonce'];
  var arrayList2 = ['Kevin', 'Bacon', 'Love', 'Hart', 'Costner', 'Spacey']
  var myObject = {};
      key = arrayList.shift();
      value = arrayList.pop();
      myObject[key] = value
  var myObj2 = {};
      key = arrayList2.shift();
      value = arrayList2.pop();
      myObj2[key] = value;
  console.log(myObject);
  console.log(myObj2);
}
transformFirstAndLast();
```

The output is this:

```
{ Queen: 'Beyonce' }
{ Kevin: 'Spacey' }
=> undefined
```

I know I am supposed to have a return statement, but I could not use two arrays for two objects within one function. Anyway, I do not know if I am doing it totally wrong or I am pretty close to find the solution, but why am I getting that "undefined" message on the third line on the output screen?

Comment: because your function doesn't return anything (=undefined) and your output comes from the console.log calls inside the function

Answer (score 3):

Just use the array indexes to get the value and create the objects:

```js
function transformFirstAndLast(array) {

  var myObject = {};
  myObject[array[0]] = array[array.length-1];
  return myObject;
}

var arrayList = ['Queen', 'Elizabeth', 'Of Hearts', 'Beyonce'];
var arrayList2 = ['Kevin', 'Bacon', 'Love', 'Hart', 'Costner', 'Spacey']

console.log(transformFirstAndLast(arrayList));
console.log(transformFirstAndLast(arrayList2));
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve the desired result, would be just to create an empty object and assign to it the first element of given array as a `key` and the last element from array as it's `value`.

```js
var arrayList = ['Queen', 'Elizabeth', 'Of Hearts', 'Beyonce'],
    arrayList2 = ['Kevin', 'Bacon', 'Love', 'Hart', 'Costner', 'Spacey'];
 

function transformFirstAndLast(array) {
  var res = Object.create(null);
      res[array[0]] = array[array.length-1];
      console.log(res);
      return res;
}

transformFirstAndLast(arrayList);
transformFirstAndLast(arrayList2);
```

Comment: Function should return `res` not `console.log` it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped! Much appreciated!

Comment: @James What's the problem to just return it? ;d

Answer (score 0):

> could anyone please explain why I am getting that "undefined" message on the third line on the output screen?

The reason why the output is:

```
{ Queen: 'Beyonce' }
{ Kevin: 'Spacey' }
=> undefined
```

is because you the function, transformFirstAndLast, does not have a `return` statement, but a function must always return something, thus it returns `undefined`.

```
function transformFirstAndLast(array) {
  var arrayList = ['Queen', 'Elizabeth', 'Of Hearts', 'Beyonce'];
  var arrayList2 = ['Kevin', 'Bacon', 'Love', 'Hart', 'Costner', 'Spacey']
  var myObject = {};
  key = arrayList.shift();
  value = arrayList.pop();
  myObject[key] = value
  var myObj2 = {};
  key = arrayList2.shift();
  value = arrayList2.pop();
  myObj2[key] = value;
  console.log(myObject);        <-- first output
  console.log(myObj2);          <-- second output
}
transformFirstAndLast();        <-- third output
```

The *third output* is calling the function, but also returning a value.  If you just had `1;` it would output `1`.

You can get around this by:

1. taking advantage of the comma operator to do something else; e.g., `transformFirstAndLast(), 'done';`
2. adding a return statement to your function `return true`; ideally, you'd want to return the object `return myObject;`

---

### Example

Here's a more robust example of how to take an array, multiple arrays, or even a bunch of strings as arguments to the function and return the created object.

```js
"use strict";

var arrayList = ['Queen', 'Elizabeth', 'Of Hearts', 'Beyonce'];
var arrayList2 = ['Kevin', 'Bacon', 'Love', 'Hart', 'Costner', 'Spacey'];

console.log(
  'Example 1 (passing arrays):\n',
  transformFirstAndLast(arrayList, arrayList2)
);
console.log(
  'Example 2 (passing strings):\n',
  transformFirstAndLast('thank','you','mother')
);


function transformFirstAndLast() {
  var obj = {}, arrs = [];
   
  if (!Array.isArray(arguments[0]))
    // handle a bunch of strings (Example 2)
    arrs = [Object.keys(arguments).map(k=>arguments[k])];
  else
    // handle 1 or more array
    arrs = [...arguments];
  
  arrs.forEach( arr => {
    obj[arr[0]] = arr[arr.length-1];
  });
  
  return obj;
}
```